#  “Confusing modifiers” reported where none are found

Tags: grammar, writing, software

I have a sentence:

> Take a look at this math problem and try to so solve it.

The Grammar Checker told me: “This sentence contains Issue: Confusing modifiers.”

But where?

Comment: yes, it is a typo!

Comment: Then you should edit the question.

Comment: @Dilawar: user471011 was actually answering my comment, but I had deleted it to post it as an answer instead.

Comment: Is that "so" your own typo? What about [beauty is unforeseeable; it cannot be deduced from past experience. Indeed when I try to **so** deduce beauty, to arrive at a mental average, the result is lifeless](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22try+to+so+deduce+beauty%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)? There's no real syntactic difference between *deduce* and *solve* here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed.

Comment: Whose software told you this?  Is this just a Microsoft bug?

Comment: @tchrist, it is grammarly.com

Comment: @user471011: grammarly.com tell me there's a "confusing modifier" when I feed it *"when I try to so deduce beauty, the result is lifeless"*. That's a problem with their analysis software, not the grammaticality of the sentence. I'm afraid finding the limitations of software style checkers is off-topic to me, so I'm voting to close despite having answered.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The modifier there is confusing. Confusing modifiers are not ungrammatical, they're just confusing. In the right context, it's clear what they refer to, but in another context, it might be impossible to tell. The diagnostic is correct, and if you weren't trying to be poetic, you would change it to something like "to deduce beauty in this way" to remove the confusion.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I wasn't trying to be "poetic" - I just picked out a written instance from Google Books of "so" validly used in a context corresponding to OP's example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Take a look at this math problem and try to <del>so</del> solve it."

The "so" is your *confusing modifier*, but this also looks like a typo?

Comment: We don't have the preceding context, but I don't think it has to be a typo.

Comment: Mightn’t it mean: *Take a look at this math problem, and try to **thus** solve it.*

Comment: @tchrist: Erm... that's what I have suggested in my answer. But OP hasn't given enough context to know if there's a plausible referent for "thus/so", so we're a bit stuck at the moment.

Comment: Or perhaps, "Take a look at this math problem and try to solve it like so."? But the OP has already admitted that it was in fact a typo in their original text, which they have copied verbatim into the question. (I actually deleted my original comment that the OP answers - a timing issue unfortunately.)

Answer (score 1):

The word *"so"* is pretty confusing there. I assume it's referring back to a specific method of solving this type of maths problem, given earlier in the text (*"so"* here means *"in such a way"*).

It would be easier to parse (and not be seen as a typo!) if the sentence were rephrased as...

> "Take a look at this math problem and try to solve it *using the method just presented*."